# What is the best way to store base64 string in MYSQL database?

Tags: java, html, mysql, hibernate, base64

I'm working on a small web application where I have to store image of a user into Mysql database. I'm new to the hibernate framework and I'm struck here. I have converted the image into Base64 string. Can anyone suggest me how to store this string into database using hibernate.

Comment: is there a reason for you to not use a blob?http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-binary-data-and-blob-mapping-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you can define a max size to your `Base64` `String`, the best way to store your image content is not to store it as `Base64` `String` but rather as an array of bytes (since it could be big) by simply defining your field with the `JPA` annotations [`@Lob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html) (stands for Large Object) and  with the `JPA` annotation [`@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html) in case you want to fetch it lazily, as next:

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private byte[] image;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the below

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "file64", columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
private byte[] file64;
```

The `LONGBLOB` allows to save larger content.